# CSS class missing on angular view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

index.html:

```
<div ng-view="myview.html"></div>
```

myview.html:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Product</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="deal in deals" class="clickableRow">
<td>{{deal.name}}</td>
<td>{{deal.product}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
      $(".clickableRow").click(function() {
            console.log("click");
      });
    }); // does nothing
console.log($(".clickableRow").length) // returns 0
```

I want to do some work when the user clicks on the clickableRows rows.

Thanks

Comment: your console.log is outside the $(document).ready so the table may not be loaded when the log line fires.  - But you really could just use the ng-click from angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you mix jquery and angularjs like this ? you can just do it with angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="deal in deals" ng-click="clickRow(deal)">
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.clickRow = function(deal) {
  console.log(deal)
}
```